# How do get the first occurrence for all ladder rows

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe consists of some integer, with key as default (int)

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'num':[3,5,6,21,3,5,6,7,3,5])
```

How is it possible to assign a new column "num_apart" that finds out difference in key between the current row and the first row that has value > x ?

Comment: Can you show the expected output, with some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

1st using `diff` to get the ladder between each row , then we using `idxmax` for finding the first occurrence of ladder exceed the boundary

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'num':[3,5,6,21,3,5,6,7,3,5]})
test['num_apart']=test.num.diff()
test
Out[118]: 
   num  num_apart
0    3        NaN
1    5        2.0
2    6        1.0
3   21       15.0
4    3      -18.0
5    5        2.0
6    6        1.0
7    7        1.0
8    3       -4.0
9    5        2.0

test.num_apart.gt(2).idxmax()# here I am using 2 as the boundary you can change the value to what you need . 
Out[119]: 3
```